# Cannot install diffusion with pip

Tags: python

I am trying to install diffusion by running `pip install diffusion` but I get the error below. I tried it with both Python version 3.10.9 and 3.9.16. I also tried it in another computer but I got "Module not found" on `diffusion.one_shot` when I use it like `from diffusion.one_shot import pose_to_video`.

```
ERROR: Cannot install diffusion==6.7.0, diffusion==6.7.10, diffusion==6.7.2, diffusion==6.7.3, diffusion==6.7.5, diffusion==6.8.0, diffusion==6.8.1, diffusion==6.8.2, diffusion==6.8.3, diffusion==6.8.4, diffusion==6.8.5, diffusion==6.8.6, diffusion==6.8.7, diffusion==6.8.8, diffusion==6.9.0 and diffusion==6.9.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    diffusion 6.9.1 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.28
    diffusion 6.9.0 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.28
    diffusion 6.8.8 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.16
    diffusion 6.8.7 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.16
    diffusion 6.8.6 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.16
    diffusion 6.8.5 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.16
    diffusion 6.8.4 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.16
    diffusion 6.8.3 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.16
    diffusion 6.8.2 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.16
    diffusion 6.8.1 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.16
    diffusion 6.8.0 depends on diffusion-core==0.0.16
    diffusion 6.7.10 depends on diffusion-cbor==6.7.10
    diffusion 6.7.5 depends on diffusion-cbor==6.7.5
    diffusion 6.7.3 depends on diffusion-cbor==6.7.3
    diffusion 6.7.2 depends on diffusion-cbor==6.7.2
    diffusion 6.7.0 depends on diffusion-cbor==6.7.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it by creating a virtual environment and adding a diffusion package to it? another option is to use a package manager like conda, which can handle dependency conflicts.